# Python ModuleNotFoundError for my main package

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

This is a follow up question for a [question I asked not long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68936664/9977758). The answer is correct and works great, but when I tried to apply it to the main package it didn't work.

Lets say I have the following files structure:

```
a/
->b/
  ->c/
    -> __init__.py
    -> script1.py
    -> script2.py
  ->d/
    -> __init__.py
    -> script3.py
```

(The `__init__` files are just like in the answer I linked above).

And in `script3.py` I import `script1.py` like so: `from b.c import script1`.

It works when I run it in Pycharm, but when I clone the repository in Colab (all this code is in a GitHub repository) I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'`

Which makes sense because my package is not in the `sys.path` variable.
And adding the folder `a` to the `sys.path` manually, after I cloned the repository, helps but it is not a real solution because I can't always do it (e.g. in unit-tests).

So my question is, how can I fix it¿ Adding the `__init__` file to folder `b` didn't help.

Notes:

1. Folder `a` is the project's folder, so it is not part of the path.
2. My GitHub repository is private, so I am not sure if making it installable (by adding setup.py and all that) would be helpful, but its my first time so I am not sure.
3. In Colab I import `script3` like so `from a.b.d import script3`. In this case I must specify folder `a` because, again, `b` is not in `sys.path`.
4. As I mentioned above, I can manually fix it in Colab but it doesn't really solves the issue, because if I want to run unit-tests for example it won't work.

Comment: How are you running your code?
`python d/script3.py` or `python b/d/script3.py`? Did you try to configure PYTHONPATH env variable in Colab?

Comment: @EmidioNeto Thanks, I have added 2 more notes to my question

Answer (score 1):

You can backwardly add folder `b` to your path and then import only from `c` folder, like this:

```py
from os.path import realpath, dirname
import sys

sys.path.append(dirname(dirname(realpath(__file__))))

from c import script1
```